# Filter array by testing against all other items using ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

I have an array of people that I would like to filter against itself (to test against all other items in the array):

```
const people = [{
  name: "James Cromwell",
  region: "Australia"
}, {
  name: "Janet April",
  region: "Australia"
}, {
  name: "David Smith",
  region: "USA"
}, {
  name: "Tracey Partridge",
  region: "USA"
}]
```

What I would like to do in this case is to be left with any people whose:

- `name`starts with the same letter
- `region` value is the same

In this case the result would be:

```
[{
  name: "James Cromwell",
  region: "Australia"
}, {
  name: "Janet April",
  region: "Australia"
}]
```

I’ve looked at doing a combination of `filter` and `any` but with no joy. My decision to use ramda here is that I’m using this in an existing ramda `compose` function to transform the data.

Comment: And what would be your expected output of it were *Debbie* Partridge instead?

Comment: In that case it would return all of the original people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group the elements by a key generated from the `region` and the 1st letter of the `name`. Reject any group with length 1, and then convert back to array with R.value, and flatten.

Note: this solution will return multiple groups of "identical" people. If you want only one group, you can take the 1st one, or the largest one, etc... instead of getting the values and flattening.

```js
const { compose, groupBy, reject, propEq, values, flatten } = R

const fn = compose(
  flatten, // flatten the array - or R.head to get just the 1st group
  values, // convert to an array of arrays
  reject(propEq('length', 1)), // remove groups with 1 items
  groupBy(({ name: [l], region }) => `${region}-${l.toLowerCase()}`) // collect into groups by the requested key
)

const people = [{"name":"James Cromwell","region":"Australia"},{"name":"Janet April","region":"Australia"},{"name":"David Smith","region":"USA"},{"name":"Tracey Partridge","region":"USA"}]

const result = fn(people)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const people = [{
  name: "James Cromwell",
  region: "Australia"
}, {
  name: "Janet April",
  region: "Australia"
}, {
  name: "David Smith",
  region: "USA"
}, {
  name: "Tracey Partridge",
  region: "USA"
}];

let output = people
    .filter((p1, i1) =>
        people.some((p2, i2) =>
            i1 !== i2 && p1.region === p2.region && p1.name[0] === p2.name[0]));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: this would have quadratic time complexity

Comment: Unless you have very large arrays, it'll still be faster than any `n log(n)` algorithms involving sorting.

Comment: ori's answer looks like `O(n)`

Comment: You're right, bucket/hash sort is `O(n)`, but I would be surprised if it's significantly faster than the nested-iteration approach for decent (<1000) size arrays.